# How to identify proccesses by X11 display?

Tags: x11, multiseat

I have a multiseat Ubuntu setup and I need to identify which processes of a graphical application are running in each X.Org display.

For example, I have two X.Org displays, :0 and :1, and two instances of Firefox running, one on each display. How do I find the PIDs of the processes of Firefox running on display :0 only?

Neither `ps -e` nor `ps -T` helped me. In both cases, I have a single "?" in TTY column for my Firefox processes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ps -e` for everything

or `ps -T` for tty

Example snippit :

```
$ ps -T
  PID  SPID TTY          TIME CMD
17764 17764 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
17815 17815 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

consult `man ps` for additional information

[source](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/basics-processes.html)